# Problems with underscore in hasMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the latest build of the capsuled eloquence version.

```
class Retailer extends Eloquent {

    // each retailer has many shipping_groups
    public function shipping_groups() {
        return $this->hasMany('ShippingGroup');
    }
}
```

The schema is

```
$capsule::schema()->create('shipping_groups', function($table) {

    $table->increments('shipping_group_id');
    $table->string('label');

});
```

but `$retailer->shipping_groups` did return `NULL` then. I tried it with `public function xy()` and it worked. As I named the SQL table `shipping_groups` as well, I also tried `$retailer->shippinggroups_test` which is obviously not of the same name and has an underscore, and this did not work either.

So, is there a general problem with underscores? In general by using in properties? Or what? Is it a bug? Or am I just too dump to see my mistakes?

Comment: 1. You may define a `protected $table` string variable in your model and set it to whatever its table is called, in case you decide to not stick to the naming conventions 2. the `shipping_groups` table does not contain a key to the `retailers` table, how is it supposed to build the relation? Sorry if I've misunderstood your schema, but something doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Will you add both models that you want to share a relationship? The `ShippingGroup` model isn't present, is it? @KaloyanDoichinov thought process is correct so this would help us decipher it further.

Comment: From the code you posted I cannot see the relationship between these two  tables as @KaloyanDoichinov said. It would be helpful if you posted the schema for retailers table or a pivot table if you have.